# A ConcurrentModificationException thrown without a modification

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I have the following Java Code:

```
HashMap<Integer, Lesson> overflow = new HashMap<Integer, Lesson>();
HashMap<Integer, Lesson> new_lessons = this.lessons;
HashMap<Integer, Lesson> lessons = this.lessons;
for (Integer lesson : lessons.keySet()) {
    if(lessons.get(lesson).getLength().equals(LessonLength.DOUBLE)){
        if(lessons.containsKey(lesson + 1)){
            overflow.put(lesson + 1, lessons.get(lesson + 1));
            new_lessons.put(lesson+1, lessons.get(lesson));
            new_lessons.get(lesson).setLength(LessonLength.ONCE);
            new_lessons.get(lesson+1).setLength(LessonLength.ONCE);
        }
        else{
            new_lessons.put(lesson+1, lessons.get(lesson));
            new_lessons.get(lesson).setLength(LessonLength.ONCE);
            new_lessons.get(lesson+1).setLength(LessonLength.ONCE);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is there thrown an ConcurrentModificationException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `new_lessons` and `lessons` variable have the same value - they're referring to the same object. So anything like this:

```
new_lessons.put(lesson+1, lessons.get(lesson));
```

... is modifying `lessons`, which you're iterating over (via its key-set). Hence the problem.

It's *possible* that if you didn't change the key set (i.e. you only changed the value associated with any entry) then you could be okay, but that's clearly not the case, because if `lessons` doesn't contain a key for `lesson + 1`, you're adding it.

It sounds like you should probably *copy* the original map for `new_lessons`, so that you've got two independent maps. Or more simply, just take a copy of the keys to start with:

```
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(lessons.keySet());
for (Integer lesson : keys) {
    ...
}
```

... and get rid of your `new_lessons` variable as it's basically pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Because `new_lessons.put(lesson+1, lessons.get(lesson));` modify `lessons' keySet()` which is the `keySet()` you are iterate over.

```
HashMap<Integer, Lesson> new_lessons = this.lessons;
HashMap<Integer, Lesson> lessons = this.lessons;
```

doesn't create new HashMap<> objects, but simple let `new_lessons` and `lessons` pointing to `this.lessons`

Answer (score 0):

`new_lessons` and `lessons` represent the same hashmap. You are altering `new_lessons` while iterating over `lessons`. Therefore you have a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

To fix this, try creating a copy of `this.lessons`.